# jq not loaded at boot (Raspbian)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cron, jq

I have a python script which uses this curl command:

```
stream = os.popen("curl -s 'http://someip/json.htm?type=devices&rid=7'| jq -r .result[].Data")
```

When i loaded this script at the boot of my raspberrypi by the fowwlong cron

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmSL elec /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/python/elec.py
```

Everything was fine. But since few days, i have this error:

```
sh: 1: jq: not found
```

If I stop the script and restart it everything is ok.

Everyone has an idea to solve that?

Comment: Why do you use python, curl and jq combined in the first place? Python already has urllib & json parser

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to "hardwire" the pathname of jq into your call to jq.

As for why the call to os.open was but is no longer working, evidently the location of jq is no longer on the PATH at the time of the call.  Presumably this means either that the location of jq has changed, or that something has changed regarding when or how PATH is set.